# C# check insert value is empty or null in cause of overwrite with empty string

Tags: c#, null, insert-update

I have a class with different attributes, lets say.

```
Object.attributeA
Object.attributeB
Object.attributeC
Object.attributeD
```

However, they are not always filled. For example:

```
Object.attributeA = "string";
Object.attributeB = "string";
Object.attributeC =  null;
Object.attributeD = "string";
```

My insert statement looks like this:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO TABLE
        (
attributeA,
attributeB,
attributeC,
attributeAD
)
values
(
@attributeA,
@attributeB,
@attributeC,
@attributeAD
);";
SqlParameter[] parameters = 
{
new SqlParameter("@attributeA", SqlDbType.NVarChar)   {Value = attributeA},
new SqlParameter("@attributeB", SqlDbType.NVarChar)   {Value = attributeB},
new SqlParameter("@attributeC", SqlDbType.NVarChar)   {Value = attributeC},
new SqlParameter("@attributeD", SqlDbType.NVarChar)   {Value = attributeD}
};
ExecuteNoNQuery(sql, parameters);
```

How do I insert a null?

(To confirm: when I update a row I want to keep the old value if the new value is null, with "" I just OVERWRITE the old value right?)

Old row
"abc" "abc" "abc" "abc"

Update row:
"string" "string" "abc" "string"

AND NOT:
"string" "string" "" "string"

EDIT:
I have two tables. I use the insert for the first table, add the attributes (sort of a temp save) AND THEN I take this table row for row update the 'real' table. The attributes in table 1 are always more then the real table. That's why after the insert of a "" I just overwrite the attribute in the real table.

My update function looks something like this:

```
public void UpdateBatchToRealTable(Class, int id)
    {
        // Current Batch
        DataTable dt = DAL.Batch(id);

        // table 1 (temp table) -> table 2 (real table) 
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

        Object.attributeA   = row["attributeA"].ToString();
        Object.attributeB   = row["attributeB"].ToString();
        Object.attributeC   = row["attributeC"].ToString();
        Object.attributeD   = row["attributeD"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: For that you first have to get all the column values (previous) and then update as per your requirement. The best i think would be to make use of the SP where it will reject null updates rather than you retriving the value first and then doing the checking.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand. When INSERT null is OK, when UPDATE null is not OK?

Comment: Your statement is INSERT statement. In that case there won't be any old value!

Comment: @Steve, yes, I have two tables, one is to make sure I inserted the values. And THEN  I take the rows and update the rows of table2.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question (you seem to be asking about UPDATE but your sample is an INSERT), you can do something like:

```
UPDATE Table
SET AttributeA = ISNULL(@AttributeA, AttributeA)
...
```

which will leave AttributeA unchanged if @AttributeA parameter is NULL (DBNull.Value).

Or if you want to ignore empty strings:

```
UPDATE Table
SET AttributeA = CASE WHEN LEN(@AttributeA) = 0 THEN AttributeA ELSE @AttributeA END
...
```

Or if you want to ignore both NULL and empty strings:

```
UPDATE Table
SET AttributeA = CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(@AttributeA,'')) = 0 THEN AttributeA ELSE @AttributeA END
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `DBNull.Value` Value in those parameter where you want to pass NULL value........

Comment: Something like this?

// If the value is not null clear to overwrite?
if (row["attributeA"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                Oject.attributeA = row["attribute"].ToString();
            }

Answer (score 0):

You could use the double question mark operator.

```
Value = attributeA ?? DBNull.Value
```

This will assign the value on the right hand side of the '??' is the value of the left hand side (attributeA in this example) is null.

You can use this in all sorts of places when you want to assign a different default value when objects could possibly be null.